# Grails Spring Security Override Current User To Lookup on Multiple Fields & Not Just Username

Tags: grails, spring-security

We have a Grails Web App using Spring Security and a User object that has username, email and fullname. In lots of places we call springSecurityService.currentUser when processing requests - this currently works fine and returns the user based on the username (which previously was always an email address and therefore was unique)

However, a change is now required where the username may not be an email and is therefore not unique in a User object - it must also take into account the optional email and fullname fields. This means that we can have two users called 'bobsmith' as long as their email/fullname values are different.

From what I can tell the springSecurity.currentUser does a lookup on the User table based on just the username - this will no longer work for us as it will probably just retrieve the first matching username it finds which could be wrong.

Is it possible to configure Grails/Spring Security to set the current user based on multiple fields. I know exactly what I want to do which is effectively in pseudo-logic (I know this is not possible):

```
if (email && !fullname) {
            springSecurityService.currentUser = User.findByUsernameAndEmail(username)
        } else if (!email && fullname) {
            springSecurityService.currentUser = User.findByUsernameAndFullname(username, fullname)
        } else if (email && fullname) {
            springSecurityService.currentUser = User.findByUsernameAndEmailAndFullname(username, email, fullname)
        }
```

The SpringSecurityService getCurrentUser() is:

```
def getCurrentUser() {
        if (!isLoggedIn()) {
            return null
        }

        def User = getClassForName(securityConfig.userLookup.userDomainClassName)

        if (principal instanceof GrailsUser) {
            User.get principal.id
        }
        else {
            User.createCriteria().get {
                String usernamePropertyName = securityConfig.userLookup.usernamePropertyName
                eq usernamePropertyName, principal[usernamePropertyName]
                cache true
            }
        }
    }
```

The last part is what is being executed in our case:

```
User.createCriteria().get {
                String usernamePropertyName = securityConfig.userLookup.usernamePropertyName
                eq usernamePropertyName, principal[usernamePropertyName]
                cache true
            }
```

Is there a way of changing this functionality somehow ? I thought about adding a custom filter into the chain but not sure if this will make any difference based on the retrieval logic that is fixed to the username property (which I don't want to change as it is correct of course).

Any help or recommendations are much appreciated

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`getCurrentUser` is a generic helper method that you never *have* to use (and it is not used by the plugin itself) - it's just there for your convenience. If it doesn't work in your application, don't use it - just create your own utility method with your custom logic.

In cases where your authentication logic is more complex than using the `username` and `password` properties, you can [register a custom UserDetailsService](https://grails-plugins.github.io/grails-spring-security-core/v3/index.html#userDetailsService) and use your logic there.

Note that the concept of the 'current user' and the logic used during authentication are typically closely related but not it all cases, so you can make either or both of these changes depending on your needs.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your reply - I sort of came to the same conclusion myself and realised that I was trying to use something that didn't really work so have indeed created a different method that now solves the issue. Learnt a lot in the process so very worthwhile. Thanks again